# How to maintain consistent coloring in ggplot with varying fail rates?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this

```
Datetime <- c("2015-09-29 08:22:00", "2015-09-29 09:45:00", "2015-09-29 09:53:00", "2015-09-29 10:22:00", "2015-09-29 10:42:00",
              "2015-09-29 11:31:00", "2015-09-29 11:47:00", "2015-09-29 12:45:00", "2015-09-29 13:11:00", "2015-09-29 13:44:00",
              "2015-09-29 15:24:00", "2015-09-29 16:28:00", "2015-09-29 20:22:00", "2015-09-29 21:38:00", "2015-09-29 23:34:00")

FailRate <- c(7,4,5.5,6,13,7.6,6.4,15.5,4.6,13.3,9.7,8.4,5.1,1.6,1.3)

df <- data.frame(Datetime,FailRate)
df$Datetime <- as.POSIXlt(df$Datetime)
```

I give the following inputs

```
UCL <- 11
limits = c(UCL)
lbls   = c('UCL')
```

I try to plot this dataframe with respect to the UCL, Upper Control Limit

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data = df,aes(x=Datetime,y=FailRate)) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=15)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5) +  ylab("Tool Fail Rate (%)") +                      
  geom_point(alpha=0.6, position=position_jitter(w=0.05, h=0.0), aes(colour=(FailRate<UCL)), size=3) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=limits,linetype=lbls)) +            
  geom_text(aes(y=limits,x=df$Datetime[15],label=paste("Rate Limit= ",round(limits, 3)),hjust=0.42,vjust=1.5)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 day"),labels = date_format("%m/%d"))
```

I get this following plot with Red indicating failures above rate limit and green indicating failures below rate limit

[image]

If I increase my UCL to 21, then I get this plot

[image]

Eventhough the failures are below the Rate Limit, they still appear Red in color. I need the plots to be consistent

```
Color = Green for Failures below Rate Limit 
Color = Red for Failures above Rate Limit
```

How can I customize it like this ?

I tried to include `scale_colour_gradient(low = "red")` but it threw me an error

Can someone provide some direction on getting this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
 scale_colour_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "red","FALSE" = "blue"))
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to createa palette with conditional statements in it:

```
pal = ifelse(FailRate< 21,'green','red')
```

This should be substituted in here:

```
  geom_point(alpha=0.6, position=position_jitter(w=0.05, h=0.0), aes(colour=pal), size=3) +
```

With the code set up this way, you can dynamically set the colors based on the condition you are evaluating.
If you needed to, you could even set it to automatically adjust in some way:

```
newRate<- max(oldRate)*.5 #any equation here would work function creating  thresholds dynamically.

pal <- ifelse(FailRate< newRate,'green','red')
```